# Delete Last Character

Tags: sql, oracle

```
StringX Varchar(30);
```

`StringX` is not a column in a table .

I have `StringX = 'He is Teacher , '`

How I can delete  the last char ( , )?

Comment: `select left('He is Teacher , ',len('He is Teacher , ')-2)`

Comment: Do you want to select without comma? Do you want to update? Do you want to do It for all values or only for this one?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `rtrim` for that:

```
select rtrim(StringX, ', ')
from   tabkeName
```

Also note you have a space before and after the `,`, so you need both `,` and  in the `rtrim` call.

Comment: ERROR : Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'rtrim' in  mysql for query : select rtrim(name,', ') from tablename;

Comment: That's not my question. I was trying the solution thought to comment for more help, but got this : select trim(trailing ',' from StringX) from tablename, and it works in MYSQL

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SUBSTR()` as:

```
select substr(stringX,1,length(stringX)-1)
```

The SUBSTR function return a portion of char, beginning at character position, substring_length characters long.

Comment: hi, can you please take a look at my question? it is similar to trimming last characters. thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69834411/update-one-column-of-each-row-in-a-table-pl-sql-unix-scripting

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
Select StringX as BeforeRemovalOfLastCharacter, left (StringX , len (StringX )-1) as AfterRemoveLastCharacter
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hi,**

There are you can try this code block; if your string is the last character is ',' **(NULL character is ignored)** then this code scope delete it.

```
select case
     when substr(replace(StringX
                        ,' ')
                ,length(replace(StringX
                               ,' '))
                ,1) = ',' then

      substr(StringX
            ,1
            ,instr(StringX
                  ,','
                  ,-1) - 1)

     else
      null
   end
from dual
```