# Update one column of each row in a table [PL/SQL, unix scripting]

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql, scripting, sql-update

i have a table with 12 columns:

table1:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 1 | 000 | aaa | zzz | 2 | 234 | OOO | 00001 | 01 | 123 | 214 |
| def | 2 | 023 | bbb | yyy | 4 | 345 | PPP | 00002 | 02 | 133 | 224 |
| ghi | 3 | 011 | ccc | xxx | 6 | 456 | QQQ | 00003 | 03 | 143 | 234 |
| jkl | 4 | 112 | ddd | www | 8 | 567 | RRR | 00004 | 04 | 153 | 244 |

i would like to use 3rd column data in a loop and fetch 'best match' data from another table.

table2:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 777 | 676 | america |
| 00 | 888 | 878 | england |
| 01 | 999 | 989 | france |
| 02 | 666 | 656 | germany |

3rd column data will be trimmed in the loop until a match in table2 is fetched.

```
first row:
iter 1: table1 row1 col3=000 -- no match in table
iter 2: table1 row1 col3=00 -- return england, replace table1 row1 col12=214 with 'england'

updated row: abc,1,000,aaa,zzz,2,234,OOO,00001,01,123,england


second row:
iter 1: table1 row2 col3=023 -- no match in table
iter 2: table1 row2 col3=02 -- return germany, replace table1 row1 col12=224 with 'germany'

updated row: def,2,023,bbb,yyy,4,345,PPP,00002,02,133,germany
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you will need to do is create a procedure, then within the procedure declare a [cursor](https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/plsql-cursor/) as well as a `variable_c_row cursor_name%ROWTYPE`.

Within the procedure, this will be the contents:

```
OPEN cursor_name

FETCH cursor_name INTO variable_c_row;

WHILE cursor_name%FOUND LOOP
    -- Declare a number variable (i)
    i := 0;
    -- Declare a varchar variable (match)
    match := variable_c_row.col3
    
    WHILE length(match) > 0 LOOP OR l_countryname IS NULL
      begin
        -- Declare a yourrow%ROWTYPE variable (l_countryname)
        SELECT col4 FROM table2 INTO l_countryname WHERE col1 = match;
        
        UPDATE table1 SET col12 = l_countryname;
      exception when no_data_found then null;
      end;

      i := i+1;
      match := substr(variable_c_row.cow3, 0, length(match)-i);
    END LOOP;
  FETCH cursor_name INTO variable_c_row;
END LOOP;

CLOSE cursor_name;
```

Since the question had no DDL or DML, the most I can provide is a broad answer, which has not been tested.

Comment: can you briefly explain these: `variable_c_row.row3`,`l_yourrow`, and the select row4 statement after begin? will try to add and run it in a shell script

Comment: @dcdum2018 Declare a variable like `variable_c_row cursor_name%ROWTYPE`. This variable will create an array and you can access any of the columns in that row by using the variable and column separated by "." Correction on the l_yourrow, meant to say l_countryname (has been edited): Use `l_countryname table2.row4%type` in your declaration.

Comment: i think row4 is col4 here -> `select col4 from table2 into l_countryname where row1 = match;` where `match := variable_c_row.row3` can you briefly explain this part? (e.g. what is row1?) thank you

Comment: Correct. It's supposed to be col4. I wrote the code without testing it and got a bit lost it seems. It's supposed to say col3, not row3. It will get your col3. Also I've corrected some of the code.

Comment: in the select statement, what is the initial value of `col1=match` ? is it the first row in table1? (`abc,1,000...`)

Comment: The initial value is table1.col3. And yes the first row within the query.

Comment: thank you! i was able to test it. only minor changes: `match := ... length(match)-1)`